# Adding digits from a number, using recursivity - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm a beginner in javascript, or any other programming language. I have managed to make a script to sum up the digits from a number.

```
function sumDigits(number){
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var result = number.toString().split("");
  var last = eval(result.join('+'));
  return last;
}
document.write(sumDigits());
```

how can I do this using a recursive function, I'm also new to the term recursive.

Comment: Is that a roundabout way of telling us that you don't know what "recursive" means?

Comment: Sum up the digits from the number? Convert it to a string, loop through it adding each number to the previous. String-Number must be converted back into a integer.

Comment: I'm just testing javascript, for myself, feel free to help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hu3Gk/

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var remainder = number % 10;
    var sum = remainder;
    if(number >= 10) {
        var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
        sum += sumDigits(rest); 
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Woops, I misunderstood the question initially. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant solution but this should do the trick.

```
function sumDigits(number) {
  // defaul the sum to 0
  var sum = 0;

  // split the number into its individual digits
  var numbers = number.toString().split("");

  // check if there are still digits in the number
  while(numbers.length > 0) {
    // add the next number (numbers[0]) to the sum
    sum += parseInt(numbers[0], 10);

    // remove the number that was just added to sum
    numbers.splice(0, 1);

    // invoke sumDigits passing the new number 
    // (the previous number excluding the first digit) 
    sumDigits(numbers.join(''));
  }

  // return the sum!
  return sum;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6RRbd/4/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this. Try:

```
function sumNums(number){
  var n = 0, num = number.toString().split('');
  for(var i in num){
    n += +num[i];
  }
  return n;
}
console.log(sumNums(125));
```

Answer (score 0):

A "recursive" function is a function that calls itself until you tell it to stop. Here's a quick example:

Oreo Cookie Tower recipe :

You will need:

1 Oreo cookie tower (optional)

1 Oreo cookie

Directions:

1. If you have an Oreo cookie tower, remove the top chocolate cookie wafer from it and eat it
2. If you have an Oreo cookie tower, remove the top chocolate cookie wafer from the Oreo cookie and eat it
3. If you have an Oreo cookie tower, place the exposed cream surface from the Oreo cookie tower against the exposed cream surface of the Oreo cookie

The whole idea is you can repeat that recipe as many times as you wanted and your cookie tower would get as big as you wanted it to be.

In that example, the word "optional" turns the Oreo Cookie Tower ingredient into another phrase you may have seen. If you ever see the term "escape condition", that's what it's referring to.

The best way to do this recursively would be with a helper function. Like this

```
function sumDigitsHelper(result){
    // check to see if result is empty here. If it is, return 0.
    // grab the first number from result here and store it in a variable called "first"
    // grab the rest of the array here and store it in a variable called "rest"
    // return first + sumDigitsHelper(rest)
}
function sumDigits(number){
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var result = number.toString().split("");
    // I'll leave this commented so you can remember what it does
    //  var last = eval(result.join('+'));
    return sumDigitsHelper(number);
}
```

Just replace my comments with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumDigits(n){
  return n == 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + sumDigits(Math.floor(n/10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to turn the number into an array, initially within the function.

Then, each time, add `array[0]` and `slice` off the first element.

```
function sumDigits (num) {
  let array = String(num).split("").map(Number);
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return array[0] + sumDigits(array.slice(1).join(""));
  }
}
console.log(sumDigits(679));
```

**NOTE** You must add `.join("")` after the `slice(1)` so that you pass a *string* into the function the second time through instead of an array.

Otherwise you'll be passing in `[6, ',', 7]`, which maps to number `[6, NaN, 7]` and then exceeds the call stack.