# Figuring out the javascript snippet behind adding the digits of number

Tags: javascript

I saw this javascript snippet/ question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626134/adding-digits-from-a-number-using-recursivity-javascript) The best answer is

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var remainder = number % 10;
    var sum = remainder;
    if(number >= 10) {
        var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
        sum += sumDigits(rest); 
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I'm trying to understand how it works. I can understand some of the lines but it's confusing though.

What I can understand is

```
var remainder = number % 10;
var sum = remainder;
```

return the remainder of the number. In other words, if the number is 145 and it's divided by 10, the remainder is 5. Therefore, the sum is 5. Next,

```
if(number >= 10) {
```

The number needs to be more than or equal to 10 because you cannot add up a single digit by itself, therefore '10' is the minimum in which you can add two digits together. Next,

```
var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
```

145 divided by 10 is 14.5. Math.floor will round it down to 14. Therefore, rest = 14. Next,

```
sum += sumDigits(rest);
```

Since rest is 14, that means that sumDigits is 14. So since the sum is 5, it adds itself to the rest. In other words, sum = 5 + 14. In conclusion, the sum is 19.

That's why it's confusing for me because it doesn't add up when 145 = 1 + 4 + 5 = 10. In other words, the sum should be 10, not 19?!?!?????

Comment: Read about recursion - that is the "point" of this function - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: *Since rest is 14, that means that sumDigits is 14* No, since `rest` is `14`, that means that `sumDigits(14)` is `5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me break it down for you：

```
sumDigits(145)
5 + sumDigits(14)
5 + 4 + sumDigits(1)
5 + 4 + 1 => 10
```

## update 1

Add the parentheses, which shows how it really works:

```
sumDigits(145)
5 + sumDigits(14)
5 + (4 + sumDigits(1))
5 + (4 + 1) 
5 + 5 => 10
```

## update 2

Actually, the intermediate results can be printed out.

```js
function sumDigits(number) {
    var temp;
    var remainder = number % 10;
    var sum = remainder;
    if (number >= 10) {
        var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
        console.log(sum + " + sumDigits(" + rest + ")");
        temp = sumDigits(rest);
        console.log(sum + " + " + temp);
        sum += temp;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sumDigits(145));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm wondering if I can ask you to become a mentor or know anyone who can become a mentor? I'm looking right now for a mentor in Javascript as I'm studying Javascript and have several questions...

Comment: @KristinaBressler My pleasure! I'm very flattered that someone ask me to become a mentor and I'd love to be your mentor, but I'm not an experienced Javascript programmer, although I have some programming backgrouds, I'm learning JS too. I know 'stackoverflow' is a great place to ask questions, a lot of people here are happy to help others solve problems and answer their questions, let's learn and make progress together!

Comment: really? this is what the function is doing? duh!

Comment: True...However, sometimes I don't get answers to some questions I've posted. Thus, that's the reason I need a mentor in which my mentor and I can discuss JS and help me review what I miss or don't understand....

Comment: @KristinaBressler  As far as I know, people here are eager to answer questions, sometimes one step behind, someone has already posted the answer you want to post. The competition is fierce, unless they don't understand the question, or the question is too big to answer, because people like specific and clear questions, or the answer is so obvious/easy that they think the one post it should do his own research.

Comment: @NabeelKhan Yes. That's how recursion works, I have updated my answer, run the snippet and you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

The funciton works fine as expected.

Once you get 19 in the end, it runs it again in same function, as 19 is greater than 10. So 1+9 would equal to 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is

> Since rest is 14, that means that sumDigits is 14.

If you ran just `sumDigit(14)`, you would sum `1` and `4` = `5`.
Then `5` is added to the original `5` in `145`

When I was thinking this through, I refactored it a bit, which helped me understand what's going on. Here's another way of thinking about it:

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var integerDigit = number % 10;

    // If there are digits remaining (i.e. not a single digit number)
    if(number >= 10) {
        // Return the current digit plus sumDigits of remaining digits
        return integerDigit + sumDigits(Math.floor(number / 10));
    }

    // If it is a single digit, just return the number
    return number;
}
```