# Understanding another Javascript snippet which add digits of a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

While this answer at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626134/adding-digits-from-a-number-using-recursivity-javascript) was the best answer due to recursion aspect,

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var remainder = number % 10;
    var sum = remainder;
    if(number >= 10) {
        var rest = Math.floor(number / 10);
        sum += sumDigits(rest); 
    }
    return sum;
}
```

there was another answer that seems easier to understand. However, there were some parts of the answer that I don't understand.

```
function sumDigits(number) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numbers = number.toString().split(""); //turn the number to string and split the number in several digits

  while(numbers.length > 0) {
    sum += parseInt(numbers[0], 10);  // covert string to number and force the number to be decimal and add the next number 
    numbers.splice(0, 1);  //remove the first digit, in other words, removing "0" from sum, i think?
    sumDigits(numbers.join('')); //join the array element into a string
  }

  return sum;
}

var sum = sumDigits(175);
$('#result').html(sum);
```

Here's what I was able to understand:

```
var numbers = number.toString().split("");
```

convert the number to string and split the string into an array of substrings. In other words, if the number is 175, it will be converted to "175" and split into 1, 7, 5. Next,

```
while(numbers.length > 0) {
```

This ensure that the number is positive and can be added. However, when I removed this line and ran it in JS Bin with a negative number, it returns an error. So somehow, this is important to sum up only the positive numbers. Next,

```
sum += parseInt(numbers[0], 10);
```

This (parseInt) convert the string or in our case, the substrings, back into numbers and add each number to itself. However I don't understand the "0" that's in the brackets after the **numbers** unless it's referring to the first number in the array = [1, 7, 5]?? Still, I can see that when I remove [0] from this line, it returns an error. Additional, with the "sum +=", it should be adding it up like this 0 + 1 + 7 + 5. Thus the sum is 13. Next,

```
numbers.splice(0, 1);
```

This is the part which I don't understand. I know that .splice either add or remove items. For example, the first part of the (0,1), which is "0", find the position of the array, in other words, "0" find the first position before "1" in the array = [1, 7, 5]. The last part, which is "1", specify the amount of items to be removed. In other words, it's asking to remove "1" from the array, causing now the array to be [7, 5]. However, I think it's not needed at all because there's no need to remove any digit from the number. Also, I don't understand the comment that said that this line remove "0" from the sum when the sum should be 13? Next,

```
sumDigits(numbers.join(''));
```

This is supposed to join the array elements into a string. In other words, it's supposed to join array = [1, 7, 5] into "1, 7, 5". Still, I don't understand why those two lines (.splice and .join) is needed when this line (sum += parseInt(numbers[0])) converts the string back into numbers and add the digits together. However when I did remove those two lines, the function doesn't work...

Please help me to understand how it works and which is execute first and so on...

Comment: Why not put a couple `console.log`s in there and see for yourself what it's doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow that response was intelligent!! I'll try to explain it:
assume that we have that string "3432"

first time we run the function we will split it:

```
numbers = ['3','4','3','2']
```

then in this loop, we will do the part the most subtile of the process, let see:

```
while(numbers.length > 0) { //actually the condition here is number array has to have at least 1 element, we'll see why
    sum += parseInt(numbers[0], 10);  // covert string to number and force the number to be decimal and add the next number 
   //so sum = 0+3 
    numbers.splice(0, 1);  //remove the first digit, in other words, removing "0" from sum, i think?
    //then here you're right, we remove the first digit so that
    number = ['4','3','2']
    sumDigits(numbers.join('')); //join the array element into a string
    //and here we call recursively sumDigits passing "432" in arguments
    /* so next time sum = 3+4, number = ['3','2'] and then 
 we will call sumDigits again with "32" as arguments 
and then sum = 7+3, number = ['2'], and then 
 we will call sumDigits again with "2" as arguments
and then sum = 10+2 and number = [] and then we will call sumDigits again passing it "" and at that time the while loop break */

  }
```

Comment: So it's another recursion function, correct? in other words, repeating the steps over and over again until there's no items in the array.

Comment: Dang! I just realized one more thing! parseInt return only the first number of the string!!! Therefore, .splice is needed to remove the first number!

Comment: I just found a shorter method while studying after I posted this question. While studying, I came across .reduce() method in which it get the sum of the numbers in the array. So in order to use the .reduce method, one will have to use .toString().split("") to return an array = ["3","4","3","2"] first. Then use the .reduce() method. Lastly, one will need to apply .Number() method to both total and currentValue to convert the "3" into 3. Here's the example: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/BpdXXq/

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost right.

The basic algorithm used is to

1. Convert the number into a string `number.toString()` and split this string into an array of characters `number.toString().split("")`, each representing one digit of the original number

   ```
   var numbers = number.toString().split("");
   ```
2. While the resulting array contains more than zero elements

   ```
   while(numbers.length > 0) {
   ```
3. Convert the first element of the Array `numbers[0]` to a number `parseInt(numbers[0], 10)` and add it to `sum`

   ```
   sum += parseInt(numbers[0], 10);
   ```
4. Remove the first element from `numbers`

   ```
   numbers.splice(0, 1);
   ```
5. Go back to 2. and repeat with the shorter array `numbers` if there are any elements left. Note that the previously second element is now the first element
6. Once `numbers` has a zero elements, return the `sum`

---

This step appears to be completely useless and should be removed:

```
sumDigits(numbers.join(''));
```

Comment: Splitting the string into an array of characters at all is needless, since JavaScript has a perfectly capable `String.prototype.slice` function. I think the author of that code was overthinking it quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addDigits(n) {
   let str = n.toString().split('');
   let len = str.length;
   let add,
       acc = 0; 
 for (i=0; i<=len-1; i++) {
   acc += Number(str[i]); 
 } 
 return acc;     
 }
 console.log( addDigits(123456789) );   //Output: 45
```