# Check Digit Sum Javascript- recursion

Tags: javascript

Looking for Javascript solution in recursion to get the sum of all digits in number until single digit come as result

For example, for the number is "55555" the sum of all digits is 25. Because this is not a single-digit number, 2 and 5 would be added, and the result, 7.

I tried the below solution based on the algorithm.

```
function getSum(n) {
let sum = 0; 
 while(n > 0 || sum > 9) 
  { 
    if(n == 0) 
    { 
        n = sum; 
        sum = 0; 
    } 
    sum += n % 10; 
    n /= 10; 
  } 
  return sum; 
 }

 console.log(getSum("55555"));
```

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626134/adding-digits-from-a-number-using-recursivity-javascript) I have found same problem here

Answer (score 1):

This would kind of work, but I'm almost sure there's a beautiful one-line solution which I just don't see yet.

```js
function singleDigitSum(str) {
  str = [...str].reduce((acc, c) => { return Number(c) + acc }, 0)
  while (str.toString().length > 1) {
    str = singleDigitSum(str.toString());
  }
  return str
}

console.log(singleDigitSum("55555"))
```

Explanation:

As a first step in your function you reassign to the parameter passed to the function the result of a reducer function which sums up all numbers in your `String`. To be able to use `Array.prototype.reduce()` function, I'm spreading your `str` into an `array` using `[...str]`.

Then, for as often as that reducer returns a value with more than one digit, rinse and repeat. When the while loop exits, the result is single digit and can be `return`ed.

Comment: it's not a pure recursion, you are using one another function  ```reduce``` here .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checSumOfDigit(num, sum = "0") {

  if (num.length == 1 && sum.length !== 1) {
    return checSumOfDigit(Number(sum) + Number(num) + "", "0");
  } else if (num.length == 1) {
    return Number(sum) + Number(num);
  }
  num = num.split("")
  sum = Number(sum) + Number(num.pop());

  return checSumOfDigit(num.join(""), sum + "")
}
console.log(checSumOfDigit("567"));
console.log(checSumOfDigit("123"));
console.log(checSumOfDigit("55555"));
```

this code might be help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need a recursion try this one

```
function CheckDigitSum(number) {

  let nums = number.split('');
  if (nums.length > 1) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(nums[i]);
    }
    return CheckDigitSum(sum.toString());    
  } else {
    return parseInt(nums[0], 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function createCheckDigit(num) {
  var output = Array.from(num.toString());
  var sum = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(output) && output.length) {
  for ( i=0; i < output.length; i++){
     sum = sum + parseInt(output[i]);
  }      
  if ((sum/10) >= 1){
    sum = createCheckDigit(sum);      
  }
 }
 return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated by recursive function.

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  // Write the code that goes here.
    if(membershipId.length > 1){
      var dgts = membershipId.split('');
      var sum = 0;
      dgts.forEach((dgt)=>{
        sum += Number(dgt);
      });
      
      //console.log('Loop 1');
      return createCheckDigit(sum + '');
  }
    else{
       //console.log('Out of Loop 1');
     return Number(membershipId);
    }
  
  
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("5555555555"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkid(num) {
    let sum = 0;
    let s = String(num);
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + Number(s[i]);
    }
    
    if(String(sum).length >= 2) return checkid(sum)
    else return sum;
}

console.log(checkid(55555);
```

Comment: The code as you have written contains a syntax error. Please test your code before submitting it. Also, you have globally defined `i`.